# FavIcon Cannot cast System.String to System.Uri

Tags: hyperlink, html

I want to add a custom favicon to SP2013.

I use the code:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/IMG/favicon.ico %>" runat="server">
```

I get the error:

> Cannot cast 'System.String' in type 'System.Uri'.

How can i use my favicon located in masterpage/IMG/... ?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint 2013